# GCC Tail Call Optimization for the Following Situation

Tags: c++, gcc, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

Below is a snippet that gets programmatically generated for a toy programming language, actual code is different but following shows what it does when executed,

```
class Base{ };

Base b;

class Derived{
      int fibo(int i){
        if(i SMALLER 2)
          return 1;
        else
          return (Derived)b.fibo(i-1) + (Derived)b.fibo(i-2);
      }
};

//then somewhere in main

b = new Derived();
int i = (Derived)b.fibo(10);
```

My question is will GCC consider this for tail call elimination?

EDIT: Turns out my my view of TOC is a bit flawed, so in a different case a different function with a single return positioned at the tail, would that be considered for optimization? The reason I ask is that there bunch of scheme to c compilers and AFAIK scheme mandates TOC so there must be a way to force this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How can it eliminate a tail call if there is no tail call? It's only a tail call if it's the very last thing done before a `return` - but you're calling it twice, storing the results somewhere, add them and *then* you return. So: Generally, no.

If the method is not virtual (i.e. GCC can be sure there's only one implementation of `fibo` that's called), it *may* still be able to optimize it (at least it worked for [one user with a free function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405770/why-are-compilers-so-stupid/414774#414774)), but you'll have to test it and propably shouldn't rely on it. Turning recursion into tail recursion is generally the programmer's job.

Comment: There are some languages that require in specification the compiler/interpreter does tail-call elimination. It is however still programmer's job to ensure it is a tail-call and this one indeed is not.

Comment: @Jan: Yes. I just realized the last sentence is nonsense for that very reason. Changed it to what I really meant.

Comment: @delnan, assuming a different function with a single return positioned at the tail? or more specifically how can i hint gcc that certain calls should be optimized?

Comment: Eliminating tail recursion is easy if the tail call is there (and detecting *that* is equally easy), so I'd expect most modern compilers to do it. You'd have to try it for your concrete code to be sure, but I for one would to assume GCC will eliminate tail calls. All of this assuming it's not a virtual call. Re hints: There is `__attribute__` etc. but you rarely need to do this for this kind of optimization (they're for things like packing structures, declaring functions as pure or stating that a pointer won't be null).

Comment: @delnan, So for my case it won't do due to Derived derived from a function interface and fibo is actually a virtual function called 'call'

Comment: Is there flag, or what have you, that enables one to detect at compile time if the compiler was able to make the function tail recursive.  So, I decorate the function with, say, an tail recursive attribute and if the compiler fails to optimize it, it flags and error and stops.

Comment: @bruce: None that I'm aware of, and neither google nor Ctrl+F in the GCC documentation helped. Perhaps tail recursion isn't used so frequently that there was significant demand for such an assertion.