# How does a compiler optimise this factorial function so well?

Tags: gcc, clang, compiler-optimization

So I have been having a look at some of the magic that is `O3` in GCC (well actually I'm compiling using Clang but it's the same with GCC and I'm guessing a large part of the optimiser was pulled over from GCC to Clang).

Consider this C program:

```
int foo(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    return n * foo(n-1);
}

int main() {
    return foo(10);
}
```

The first thing I was pretty WOW-ed at (which was also WOW-ed at in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/414774/1068248) was how `int foo(int)` (a basic factorial function) compiles into a tight loop. This is the ARM assembly for it:

```
    .globl  _foo
    .align  2
    .code   16
    .thumb_func _foo
_foo:
    mov r1, r0
    movs    r0, #1
    cbz r1, LBB0_2
LBB0_1:
    muls    r0, r1, r0
    subs    r1, #1
    bne LBB0_1
LBB0_2:
    bx  lr
```

Blimey I thought. That's pretty interesting! Completely tight looping to do the factorial. WOW. It's not a tail call optimisation since, well, it's not a tail call. But it appears to have done a much similar optimisation.

Now look at `main`:

```
    .globl  _main
    .align  2
    .code   16
    .thumb_func _main
_main:
    movw    r0, #24320
    movt    r0, #55
    bx  lr
```

That just blew my mind to be honest. It's just totally bypassing `foo` and returning `3628800` which is `10!`.

This makes me really realise how your compiler can often do a much better job than you can at optimising your code. But it raises the question, **how does it manage to do such a good job**? So, can anyone explain (possibly by linking to relevant code) how the following optimisations work:

1. The initial `foo` optimisation to be a tight loop.
2. The optimisation where `main` just goes and returns the result directly rather than actually executing `foo`.

Also another interesting side effect of this question would be to show some more interesting optimisations which GCC/Clang can do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you compile with `gcc -O3 -fdump-tree-all`, you can see that the first dump in which the recursion has been turned into a loop is `foo.c.035t.tailr1`. This means the same optimisation that handles other tail calls also handles this slightly extended case. Recursion in the form of `n * foo(...)` or `n + foo(...)` is not that hard to handle manually (see below), and since it's possible to describe exactly how, the compiler can perform that optimisation automatically.

The optimisation of `main` is much simpler: inlining can turn this into `10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1`, and if all the operands of a multiplication are constants, then the multiplication can be performed at compile time.

**Update**: Here's how you can manually remove the recursion from `foo`, which can be done automatically. I'm not saying this is the method used by GCC, but it's one realistic possibility.

First, create a helper function. It behaves exactly as `foo(n)`, except that its results are multiplied by an extra parameter `f`.

```
int foo(int n)
{
    return foo_helper(n, 1);
}

int foo_helper(int n, int f)
{
    if (n == 0) return f * 1;
    return f * n * foo(n-1);
}
```

Then, turn recursive calls of `foo` into recursive calls of `foo_helper`, and rely on the factor parameter to get rid of the multiplication.

```
int foo(int n)
{
    return foo_helper(n, 1);
}

int foo_helper(int n, int f)
{
    if (n == 0) return f;
    return foo_helper(n-1, f * n);
}
```

Turn this into a loop:

```
int foo(int n)
{
    return foo_helper(n, 1);
}

int foo_helper(int n, int f)
{
restart:
    if (n == 0) return f;
    {
        int newn = n-1;
        int newf = f * n;
        n = newn;
        f = newf;
        goto restart;
    }
}
```

Finally, inline `foo_helper`:

```
int foo(int n)
{
    int f = 1;
restart:
    if (n == 0) return f;
    {
        int newn = n-1;
        int newf = f * n;
        n = newn;
        f = newf;
        goto restart;
    }
}
```

(Naturally, this is not the most sensible way to manually write the function.)

Comment: Excellent answer! And yes the `main` optimisation indeed can be just replaced with constants multiplied together so that one is easy. I like your walk through of the `foo` optimisation :-).